# How can I RUN JAVAWS command line in text-mode Linux environment?

Tags: java-web-start

I want to RUN JAVAWS command line in text-mode Linux environment and I have not X.
Is it possible? 
Tanx

Answer (score 3):

How about `javaws -wait -Xnosplash -import -silent http://...`

After this maybe you can help me with [Are javaws exit codes really broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803823/are-javaws-exit-codes-really-broken)