# Are javaws exit codes really broken?

Tags: java, jnlp, exit-code, java-web-start

I was working to automate same java code execution using JNLP and I was surprised to discover that jawaws did not gave me a valid return code.

Original execution line was:

```
javaws -wait http://example.com:666/missing.jnlp
```

This did showed an ugly window with **"Unable to launch application."** message.

As you can image I tried to make this not require a GUI and tried:

```
javaws -wait -Xnosplash -import -silent http://example.com:666/missing.jnlp
```

But even if this command fails, it will still return `0`, success.

How to solve this?

Comment: The Sun/Oracle site is in a  bit of a mess at the moment, but have you checked the bug database?  Note that I had heard reports that it is very slow *if you are logged in* to the site.

Comment: As you can imagine I tried this yesterday and it was impossible to use. Maybe they have problems with the database backend, expired license ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Bug ID 6898437](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6898437) in the Oracle/Sun bug tracker, and is fixed in more recent releases.

Comment: Thanks for putting the link but still I do not see it marked as solved and the tracker login fails to give any response (same behavior as 3 months ago). One more reason to step away from Java. I don't wan't to know what is happening inside Oracle these days.

Comment: I can't log in either, but that link includes the following information: "State 11-Closed, Verified, request for enhancement" and "Release Fixed 6u21-rev(b08), 7(b119) (Bug ID:2184659), 6u23(b02) (Bug ID:2189374) , 6u22-rev(b05) (Bug ID:2199472)". I have verified that it works for me using jdk1.6.0_23. What is happening inside Oracle is another question...

Comment: Actually I can log in, but it took a few minutes for the login page to respond.